# Confirmation on the UPS Rate API test URL

Tags: rest, ups

I have downloaded the UPS Rate API zip file and the JSON documentation uses [https://wwwcie.ups.com/ship/{version}/rating{requestoption}](https://wwwcie.ups.com/ship/%7Bversion%7D/rating%7Brequestoption%7D) for the POST request to get information.

Watching a youtube video from 2018 however shows a different set of documentation and a different POST URL (https://wwwcie.ups.com/rest/Rate)

I can get a response from the URL on the outdated documentation and have found a few other articles/questions that are using the older URL even recently, but all I ever get from the URL in the current documentation is an Invalid Access License Number error even though the number is correct.

Can anyone shed some light on what the difference is between these two are?

Answer (score 0):

Surely one of those urls is the shipping api, the other is rate?

URLS change depending on format JSON or XML or whatever.